# Javascript Loops: for-loop works but not map?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, dictionary, ecmascript-6

I'm working with mockData for a web app and I'm trying to loop over nested objects. My problem is that a for loop works but not array.map and don't know why.

Here is the for loop:

```
  for (let i = 0; i < fakeChartData.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < fakeChartData[i].poll.length; j++) {
      if (fakeChartData[i].poll[j].id === id) {
        return fakeChartData[i].poll[j]
      }
    }
  }
```

And here is the map loop:

```
  fakeChartData.map(data => {
    data.poll.map(data => {
      if (data.id === id) {
        return data;
      }
    });
  });
```

My Data structure:

```
fakeChartData = [
  {
    id: '232fsd23rw3sdf23r',
    title: 'blabla',
    poll: [{}, {}]
  },
  {
    id: '23dgsdfg3433sdf23r',
    title: 'againBla',
    poll: [{}, {}]
  }
];
```

I'm trying to load the specific object with the id passed to it on onClick method.
Here is the full function:

```
export const fetchPollOptById = (id) =>
  delay(500).then(() => {
    for (let i = 0; i < fakeChartData.length; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < fakeChartData[i].poll.length; j++) {
        if (fakeChartData[i].poll[j].id === id) {
          return fakeChartData[i].poll[j]
        }
      }
    }
});
```

Comment: you should provide an example of data structure...

Comment: How is this run? We have problems with using array.map in our tests. They are run using jasmine and phantom.js. Phantom.js seems to be missing support for array.map

Comment: Consider what the `return` statement inside the `map` is returning from.

Comment: The if statement make me think  you mix up .map() with .filter(). map should *always* return a value while filter is for returning an array that only contain the elements that meet your criterion

Comment: @mortb I did try to use .filter() but it seemed to return the original data rather than the computed one. Weird and I know it's my fault.

Comment: You need to show a complete example of how you're using this code and what you expect it to return.

Comment: @TomFenech Added the full code.

Comment: Presumably the objects in each `poll` array aren't normally empty?

Comment: Your poll objects don't have `id` properties but from you code it seems like they should.

Comment: Each function has it's own returned value! Your `map` effectively doesn't do anything. It returns a new array and you don't store/use it. Based on the logic of your `for` loop you don't need to use the `map` method. It's not the method that you are looking for.

Comment: @TomFenech Yes they aren't empty, they are filled with ChartJs data and they do have ids.

Comment: @otajor I'm looping through `poll` again so I can access the internal data. 
The first one goes through the `whole array`  & the second one through `poll`.

Comment: @Khpalwalk you are trying to compare `fakeChartData[i].poll[j].id`, but your poll objects are empty: `poll: [{}, {}]` - surely it should be something like `poll: [{id: 23}, {id: 24}]`

Comment: @otajor They are filled with data, like what you have posted.

Comment: `map` does something completely different. Why did you want to use it in the first place? _"I did try to use .filter() but it seemed to return the original data rather than the computed one"_ Just like your code. What's your point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm right about what you're trying to do, this should work:

```
return fakeChartData.reduce((acc, data) => acc.concat(data.poll), [])
                    .filter(pollObj => pollObj.id === id)[0]
```

First it makes an array containing all the poll objects from different data objects, then it filters them to find the one with the correct id and returns that object.

As to why your approach using `map` does not work: you are using it in the wrong way. What `map` does it to take a function and apply it to every member of an array.

Here's an array and function kind of like yours:

```
const arr = [1,2,3]
const getThingById(id) => {
  var mappedArray = arr.map(x => {
    if(x === id) return x
  })
  console.log(mappedArray) // [3]
}
getThingById(3) // undefined
```

This won't work. `getThingById` has no return statement. The return statement `return x` is **returning something from the function that is passed into map**. Basically, you shouldn't be using `map` to do what you're trying to do. `map` is for when you want to return an array.

Comment: This works but I was looking into why wasn't the .map() not working. I've already got the example to work with plain for-loops.

Comment: Your example with map does not work, because the return statement only exits the second callback. Both callbacks will still iterate the whole arrays. The array you will get as a result from your example will only contain undefined. [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: @R.Schmitt Thanks for the explanation. The others just gave me their solution with nothing as to "because". Thanks

Comment: @otajor I will accept your answer is it is the shortest and also immutable.

Comment: Cheers for accepting - I just edited with some more explanation about why map doesn't work. I would suggest you do some more reading about `map`, `filter`, `reduce` and `forEach` and figure out when you should use each one.

Comment: @Khpalwalk The most important thing about `map` is that it maintains the structure of the original array that is, you pass an array of three elements to `map` and get back an array of exactly three (transformed) elements.

Answer (score 3):

A return statement inside a for loop causes your function to return. However, a return statement inside a .map() function's callback only returns the callback and this returned value is then placed in the new array. Please see the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).If you really want to be using .map(), you could do it like this:

```
export const fetchPollOptById = (id) => {
    var result;
    fakeChartData.map(data => {
        data.poll.map(data => {
            if (data.id === id) {
                result = data;
                return data;
            }
        });
    });
    return result;
}
```

note: I also assume that your poll objects have an id field like this:

```
  fakeChartData = [
      {
          id: '232fsd23rw3sdf23r',
          title: 'blabla',
          poll: [
              {id: 'pollId1', otherField: 'blah'},
              {id: 'pollId2', otherField: 'blah'}
          ]
      },
      {
          id: '23dgsdfg3433sdf23r',
          title: 'againBla',
          poll: [
              {id: 'pollId3', otherField: 'blah'},
              {id: 'pollId4', otherField: 'blah'}
          ]
      }
  ];
```

You can then get the poll data like this:

```
fetchPollOptById("pollId3"); //returns {id: "pollId3", otherField: "blah"}
```

Comment: I got it now mate but thanks anyways. Though, your answer is close to what I want but I already accepted someone else's answer but If I could do it again, then it would be your answer. 
Cheers

Comment: You have the option to change the accepted answer as you are the author of the question, but only do it if you see my answer as more helpful to you. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93969/is-changing-the-accepted-answer-frowned-upon

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
fakeChartData.map(data => {
    var result = data.poll.map(data => {
      if (data.id === id) {
        return data;
      }
    });
    return result;
  });
```

It should work. And yeah you should use `find()` instead of `map()` I think.

Comment: .find is not supported by IE

Answer (score 1):

A bit long implementation:

```
let results = fakeChartData.map(data => {
    let innerResult = data.poll.filter(data => {
      if (data.id === id) {
        return data;
      }
     return innerResult.length ? innerResult[0] : null;
    });
  })
  .filter(x => (x !== null));
let whatYouwant = results.lenght ? results[0] : null;
```

If you can use find() it would look nicer, but that depends on what browsers you need to support